# PHP Soap Issue: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm using PHP 5.2.5.5 with Moodle 1.9.

When I make a simple SOAP call without parameters, it works.  However, as soon as I use a call with a parameter, it fails.  If I capture the SOAP request with Fiddler, I see that it's not adding the parameter to the soap request at all.

Here's my sample code:

```
$WSDL = 'http://www.nanonull.com/TimeService/TimeService.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new SoapClient($WSDL);
$response = $client->getUTCTime(); // WORKS
$response = $client->getTimeZoneTime('ZULU');  // SOAP FAULT
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the name of that parameter as well (and pass in an array):

```
$WSDL = 'http://www.nanonull.com/TimeService/TimeService.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new SoapClient($WSDL);
$response = $client->getUTCTime(); // WORKS

$response = $client->getTimeZoneTime(array('timezone'=>'ZULU')); //works
print_r( $response);
```

see: http://www.nanonull.com/TimeService/TimeService.asmx?op=getTimeZoneTime

and: http://www.nanonull.com/TimeService/TimeService.asmx

Jack

Comment: Also check the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) in the comments there is a mention of .NET web services and needing to set up a mini-class.

Comment: man. I just want to hug you. You eased my life. I wish that I could give you 10 votes.